# How can i compare two arrays of different length and keys on the basis of matching key values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**I have tried this, but it is giving the correct result**

**Array1**

```
Array1: [
  {
    id: 2,
    city: 'washington',
    code: 0099,
    room: 5,
    ...
  },
  {
   ...
  },
  ...
]
```

**Array 2**

```
 Array2: [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "john"
        "number": 727625,
        "etage": 5,
        "status": 0,
        ...
      },
      {
       ...
      },
      ...
    ]
```

**My Code**

```
 let Result = [];
           if (Array1 && Array1.length > 0 && Array2 && Array2.length > 0) {       
               Array1.forEach((arr1, index) => {
                 Array2.forEach((arr2, index) =>{              
                   if (arr1.id === arr2.id && arr1.room === arr2.etage) {
                      Result.push(arr1)
                   }
                 })
               })
           }
        console.log(Result)
```

**What I want ?**

I want items(objects) of **Array1** by comparing both arrays, where
both have same id's && room from **Array1's** object equal to the etage
from **Array2's** object.

Please guide me, how can I do this in ES6 style in React js?

Comment: You seem to know what you want, so may you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: ust using the [Array iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods) built into JS is fine for this:

Comment: @evolutionxbox i edited my question , please check now

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with nested loops is the unnecessary iteration of each element of the first array and multiple iterations of the second array.

This approach takes two loops, one for generating all keys from `array2` and the other to filter `array1`.

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for compound key of `id` and `etage` and filte the array for getting the items with same `id` and `room`.

```
const
    getKey = (...values) => values.join('|'),
    keys = new Set(array2.map(({ id, etage }) => getKey(id, etage))),
    result = array1.filter(({ id, room }) => keys.has(getKey(id, room));
```

---

With condition

```
room > etage
```

and a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```
const
    ids = array2.reduce(
        (m, { id, etage }) => m.set(id, Math.min(etage, m.get(id) || 0)),
        new Map
    ),
    result = array1.filter(({ id, room }) => room > ids.get(id));
```

Comment: ok, please also tell about the condition => if (room > etage) ?

Comment: @hafizadeel, where is the condition `room > etage` coming from?

Comment: In case , if I want to make condition, where room in any of Array1's object greater than etage in any of Array2's object  ?

Comment: that is a more complex problem, because you need the minimum value of `etage`. In this case, i would take a `Map` with `id` as key and the minimum as value.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```js
Array1= [
  {
    id: 2,
    city: 'washington',
    code: 0099,
    room: 5,
    }
 
];
Array2= [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "john",
        "number": 727625,
        "etage": 5,
      },

    ];
    
 const result = Array1.filter(a1 => Array2.find(a2 => a1.id == a2.id) && Array2.find(a2 => a1.room ==  a2.etage));
 
 console.log(result);
```

That will return a filtered array by room, etage and id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` and `some` ES6 methods:

```js
  const arr1 = [
    {
      id: 1,
      room: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      room: 5
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      room: 3
    }
  ];
  const arr2 = [
    {
      id: 0,
      etage: 0
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      etage: 5
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      etage: 3
    }
  ];

  const getTheSame = (arr1, arr2) => {
    return arr1.filter(o1 =>
      arr2.some(o2 => o1.id === o2.id && o1.room === o2.etage)
    );
  };
  console.log("Result: ", getTheSame(arr1, arr2));
```